# Max request per sec/hour for a VF page webform

Tags: visualforce, performance

We have a VF page as a webform and hosted as a Salesforce site.Because there are lot of requests hitting it,is it possible for us to get an estimate of how many requests can it handle per sec/hour?Is there a way to perform a load testing for this VF page.Can we use Event monitoring to find out max requests it can handle at once?
Any immediate response is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Performance testing is not allowed without [advanced notice](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335652&type=1&mode=1).

> Sometimes changes and customizations to your Salesforce implementation impact performance. Before going into production, it is wise to run sandbox performance tests, please read Methods of Locating and Testing for Performance Issues. Salesforce is a multi-tenant environment. If you decide to test, you will need to schedule this with Support so Salesforce can monitor activity levels.

...

> Performance tests must be submitted for approval at least two weeks in advance of the testing date(s), requests without a two week notice may be denied. To submit the request, navigate to the Help portal and select Network and Performance > Notify Salesforce of an upcoming activity > Schedule a Performance Test

---

Note that the basic limits are determined by the [Site.com limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_limits.htm&type=5). If you need more than this amount of power, you can negotiate for additional power (bandwidth, CPU time, etc). Contact your account executive for more information. That said, you can estimate how much data and CPU your page uses, divide it in to the Site.com limits, and you'll have an estimate to how many requests you can handle.